# Grep only 2 portions in a line

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have the following line. I can grep one part but struggling with also grepping the second portion.

Line:

```
html:<TR><TD>PICK_1</TD><TD>36.0000</TD><TD>1000000</TD><TD>26965</TD><TD>100000000</TD><TD>97074000</TD><TD>2926000</TD><TD>2.926%</TD><TD>97.074%</TD></TR>
```

I want to have the following results after grepping this line.

PICK_1 97.074%

Currently just grepping first portion via following command.

```
grep -Po "<TR><TD>[A-Z0-9_]+" test.txt
```

Appreciate any help on how I can go about doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use awk with a custom field separator:

```
awk -F'[<>TDR/]+' '{ print $2, $(NF-1) }' file
```

This splits the line on things that look like one or more opening or closing `<TD>` or `<TR>` tags, and prints the second and second-last field.

Warning: this will break on almost every input except the one that you've shown, since awk, grep and friends are designed for processing text, not HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If you always have the same number of fields delimited by "TD" tags, you can try with this (dirty) `awk`:

```
awk -F'[<TD>|</TD>]' '{print $8 " " $80}'
```

Or this combination of `column` and `awk`:

```
column -t -s "</TD>" | awk -F' ' '{print $3 " " $11}'
```

Or with `sed` instead of `column`:

```
sed -e 's/<TD>/ /g' | awk -F' ' '{print $3 " " $11}'
```

Answer (score 0):

try provide each patter after "-e" option

```
grep -e PICK_1 -e "<TR><TD>[A-Z0-9_]+" test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[<>]' '{print $5,$(NF-4)}' file
PICK_1 97.074%
```